# Is there a cleaner way to write this avoiding includes

Tags: php, mysql, html, dynamic

I'm writing a project in php that will basically give me a webpage with links to things like:

- a page containing my favorite youtube videos stored in a mysql db
- a page with all my favorite games
- and music ect

All will be embeded directly inside the webpage rather than linking to the site.

To simplify this I've made a master template "index.php" and then using `$_GET` I pass pages and other info through to the template which is then handled by a page check script which performs a number of ifs to determine what php script to load into the website.

Where my question lies is whats the prefered method for loading theese scripts into the website as my current method is

```
if ($_GET["page"] == "videos"){
    include ("dynapage/scripts/videos/videos.php");
}

if ($_GET["page"] == "music"){
    include ("dynapage/scripts/music/music.php");
}
```

ect

Is using includes to add this code into my template a good thing to do or is there a better method you can suggest?

note: checks for `isset` are already included in the checks and aditional pbs are availble on request.

Comment: Use an array which has the `$_GET["page"]` value as key and the php filename as value. You then only need to check if it is inside the array and if so, include it. You then write the values into the array instead of writing many `if` clauses.

Comment: on a note ive just realised this wont be a problem for my project but wouldnt this be suceptable to hacking by replacing the $_GET url with a file name and it loading that file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe Something like this:

```
$config = array(
    'videos' => 'dynapage/scripts/videos/videos.php',
    'music' => 'dynapage/scripts/music/music.php'
);

if(isset($config[$_GET['page']])) {
     include($config[$_GET['page']]);
}
```

is a bit better, then writing many if clauses (;

Answer (score 6):

Use an array which has the `$_GET["page"]` value as key and the php filename as value. You then only need to check if it is inside the array and if so, include it. You then write the values into the array instead of writing many `if` clauses.

The following code example shows this, additionally it has a function to load a page because so the included script does not set variables in the context it gets included into by accident.

```
$pages = array(
    'videos' => 'videos/videos.php',
    'music' => 'music/music.php',
);

/**
 * include a page template
 */
function load_page(array $pages, $page, $path = 'dynapage/scripts')
{
    if (isset($pages[$page])) return;
    include ($path.'/'.$pages[$page]);
}

if (isset($_GET['page']))
{
    load_page($pages, $_GET['page']);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your post i do like it in that it prevents hacks regarding false $_GET value however i couldnt use it as i dont get how to edit it if i choose to have all files insiide the scripts directory rather than scripts/videos/video.php i could use /scripts/videos.php

Comment: Yeah there is an error with the function for the path-prefix. It's just an example, edit it for your own needs, you can use fully-qualified path's as well.

Comment: i went with ahmets one as it uses the same basic concepts but works for files in the root of scripts id of modified yours but my php is basic at best but i apreciate your contribution

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can just do:

```
if( file_exists($fn = "dynapage/scripts/".$_GET['page']."/".$_GET['page'].".php"))
    include($fn);
```

Comment: thanks so much that makes so much more sense than using multiple ifs i would gladly vote you up but i dont have 15 rep so please accept my many gratefull thanks

Comment: Not secure, go with hakre's or ahmet's answer with the control array so that only properly approved pages are loaded.